# How many worlds are in the galactic map?

Tags: mass-effect

The galactic map is large, and difficult to navigate quickly. Just looking for a summary of how many worlds I'd be hitting if I decided to see it all - are we talking dozens? Hundreds?

Comment: +1 for sticking with it and not giving up.  By the way, we'd be happy to help you with any questions you have about how the site works.  Just visit [chat] when you get 20 rep.

Comment: Gave you +1 for willingness to learn despite resistance from the community. Respect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the good news is that the number of explorable planets is a much smaller subset than the number of total planets in game. You can see the list of *every* planet and scannable object [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Index) , but note that for a good 60% of those planets, there is text only -- no mission, possibly some resources or collectibles, and a description of the planet's characteristics.

More relevantly, there are a total of **39** systems, each of which generally has one mission on it, with the hub planets, of the Citadel, Noveria, and Feros having more than one (though they take place in the same relative area).

So all in all, there may be a lot of worlds, and space may be big (really big), but "exploring it all" is something that is wholly manageable, and easily achieved by those willing to dedicate the time to it.

Comment: Space is indeed very big. "You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mindbogglingly big it is. I mean, you may think it's a long way down the road to the chemist's, but that's just peanuts to space."